# saving contacts on iPhone 6 without bringing documents and data

Tags: iphone, icloud, contacts, data

This has always been frustrating. I've restored my iPhone 6 a number of times, but when I bring the contacts from iCloud, the documents and data comes along for the ride. Is there any way to save contacts without anything else? I want to free up to my original amount of space.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > iCloud > iCloud Drive and turn it off.
If you only want contacts you can turn off everything else you don't need there as well (Photos, Mail, etc.)